# 2D arrays, Strings, doubles and addition

Tags: java, arrays, string, text, double

My assignment is to create a program that will scan in a text file that contains the students details and grades for 4 assignments which will then be broken down into both Strings (the details) and doubles (the students grades) and to finally calculate the average for each students grade and then an average for each Assignment. The Final output should look like this(got it from my assignment sheet):

```
Student Name     FAN       Part 1  Part 2 Part 3 Part 4 Mark   Grade
Adam Adamson     adam0001  85.4    79.8   82.4   86.1   82.77% HD
Bethany Bright   brig0001  89.7    85.6   84.2   82.9   84.92% DN
Cameron Carlson  carl0001  55.45   49.82  60.4   42.27  50.23% P
David Dawson     daws0001  72.6    78.49  80.2   65.88  74.46% CR
Evelyn Ellis     elli0001  50.2    35.88  48.41  58.37  46.57% FA
Frances Fitz     fitz0001  78.9    75.67  82.48  79.1   78.38% DN
Greg Gregson     greg0001  24.3    32.88  29.72  28.4   30.05% F
Harriett Hope    hope0001  52.2    58.93  61.5   63.44  60.12% P
Ivan Indigo      indi0001  88.4    91.23  90.05  92.46  91.08% HD
Jessica Jones    jone0001  82.33   89.74  81.3   84.85  85.84% HD
                  Average  67.948  67.804 70.066 68.377 68.44% CR
                                                StdDev 19.4441
```

In the text file there are 10 lines, first line is:

Adam Adamson,adam0001,85.4,79.8,82.4,86.1

and so on for 10 randomly created students. I have 3 classes, a main class called Topic Management, a StudentMarks class (for the students grades) and a Student class (for the name and the FAN (the adam0001 part)). I have created an array that stores all the scores called marks.
I am able to print out the name and the FAN and am also able to assign the grades into doubles using double score1 = double.parseDouble(); etc. each score has it's own method which I am then calling in the main class.

The trouble I am having is getting each column of results to print out next to the name and the fan. At the moment they just print out in single column below. 
Then I need to calculate the averages, i'm not sure how to go about it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is my program so far:

This is my Main Class - Topic Management:

```
public class TopicManagement 
{

ArrayList part1 = new ArrayList(10);
ArrayList part2 = new ArrayList(10);
ArrayList part3 = new ArrayList(10);
ArrayList part4 = new ArrayList(10);

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{   

    System.out.println("Hello, Welcome to the Student Assesment Calculator");
    System.out.println("Student Name \t  FAN \t\tScore 1\tScore2\tScore 3\tScore 4\tTotal");

    Student student = new Student();
    StudentMarks studentMarks = new StudentMarks();

    for (int row = 0; row < nameFan.length; row++) 
    {
         System.out.println(nameFan[row][0] + "\t " + nameFan[row][1] + "\t ");
         //System.out.println("");
    }

    for (int col = 0; col < marks.length; col++)
    {
        double score1 = Double.parseDouble(marks[col][2]);
        double score2 = Double.parseDouble(marks[col][3]);
        double score3 = Double.parseDouble(marks[col][4]);
        double score4 = Double.parseDouble(marks[col][5]);

        part1.add(score1);
        part2.add(score2);
        part3.add(score3);
        part4.add(score4);

        System.out.println(part1.get(col) + "\t" + part2.get(col) + "\t" + 
                           part3.get(col) + "\t" + part4.get(col) + "\t");


    }

}//end of method
}//end of class
```

The Student Class:

```
public class Student 
{           //ROW, COL
    String[][] nameFan = new String[10][6];
            //this method outputs the name and fan
public void student() throws IOException 
{   
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File ("TestResults.txt"));


    for (int row = 0, col; row < nameFan.length; row++)
    {
        Scanner lineRead = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
        lineRead.useDelimiter(",");

        col = 0; // Starting at column 0 for each row

        while (lineRead.hasNext()) //Check for next
        {
            nameFan[row][col]=lineRead.next();

            col++; // Move on to the next column   
        }
    }
}//end of nameFan method
}//end of class
```

Then finally the StudentsMarks class:

```
public class StudentMarks 
{                 
        //ROW, COL
String[][] marks = new String[10][6];

        //was going to call the method 'student' but would have been confusing with the student class
public String[][] studentMarks() throws IOException 
{  
    Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File ("TestResults.txt"));


    for (int row = 0, col; row < marks.length; row++)
    {
        Scanner lineRead = new Scanner(scan.nextLine());
        lineRead.useDelimiter(",");

        col = 0; //Starting at column 0 for each row

        while (lineRead.hasNext()) //Check for next
        {
            marks[row][col]=lineRead.next();

            col++; // Move on to the next column
        }
    }

    return marks;
}   
}
```

The output of this now looks like:

```
Hello, Welcome to the Student Assesment Calculator
Student Name      FAN       Score 1 Score2  Score 3 Score 4 Total
Adam Adamson     adam0001    
Bethany Bright   brig0001    
Cameron Carlson  carl0001    
David Dawson     daws0001    
Evelyn Ellis     elli0001    
Frances Fitz     fitz0001    
Greg Gregson     greg0001    
Harriett Hope    hope0001    
Ivan Indigo      indi0001    
Jessica Jones    jone0001    
85.4    79.8    82.4    86.1    
89.7    85.6    84.2    82.9    
55.45   49.82   60.4    42.27   
72.6    78.49   80.2    65.88   
50.2    35.88   48.41   58.37   
78.9    75.67   82.48   79.1    
24.3    32.88   29.72   28.4    
52.2    58.93   61.5    63.44   
88.4    91.23   90.05   92.46   
82.33   89.74   81.3    84.85
```

Ok, so what i have done now is no longer am i calling the output from the methods in the student and studentMarks class. I am taking the arrays and putting them into ArrayLists (part1, part2 etc.) and then printing those Array Lists. I am still having trouble with the format of the output. I can't get them on the same line. I understand what you mean by the println and print lines but i need those within the loops otherwise they student names and fans etc. will just print everything out on one line, won't it?

And i'm not sure how to now calculate the averages(or marks as a %, depends how you read it) I'm hoping that now they are in an ArrayList it will be easier but i'm not sure how to get started.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `System.out.print` and `System.out.println`?

Comment: I made an edit, does that make more sense to you now?

Answer (score 1):

In your score methods you have a `println`

```
System.out.print(score4);
System.out.println("\t4");  //Notice this is a println
```

`println` will print then prints a new line, change these to a `print` then on the first/last one add a new line character or a `println`

**EDIT**

You are now putting the scores into an ArrayList and then printing the ArrayList within the same loop. This is pointless as this

```
for (int col = 0; col < marks.length; col++)
{
    double score1 = Double.parseDouble(marks[col][2]);
    double score2 = Double.parseDouble(marks[col][3]);
    double score3 = Double.parseDouble(marks[col][4]);
    double score4 = Double.parseDouble(marks[col][5]);

    part1.add(score1);
    part2.add(score2);
    part3.add(score3);
    part4.add(score4);

    System.out.println(part1.get(col) + "\t" + part2.get(col) + "\t" + 
                       part3.get(col) + "\t" + part4.get(col) + "\t");
}
```

Could just be done with this

```
for (int col = 0; col < marks.length; col++)
{
    System.out.println(marks[col][2] + "\t" + marks[col][3] + "\t" + 
                       marks[col][4] + "\t" + marks[col][5] + "\t");
}
```

Notice how you still have two loops and are still printing a line for each iteration of the loop, just do this to get the output you want since all your arrays are the same length

```
for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(nameFan[i][0] + "\t " + nameFan[i][1] + "\t
                       marks[i][2] + "\t" + marks[i][3] + "\t" + 
                       marks[i][4] + "\t" + marks[i][5] + "\t");
}
```

Ideally your `Student` Class should only hold the information of one Student and then you do not need an array. Likewise your StudentMarks class should only have the marks of one student, and then part of student would have a `StudentMarks` property. Then you could just have an ArrayList of `Students` like this `ArrayList<Student>` then you would just have to have in your student object class a `toString()` method which would print a line in the format you want.

Comment: I've made an edit so if that helps you help me that'd be great!
Cheers

Comment: Awesome! that helps my output massively but how would you then calculate the averages? isn't the data remaining a string when it should be a double?

Comment: Can you help me with that?

Comment: Only the Output is a string, your data is still in the arrays as doubles. So you can just loop again to calculate averages.